# Site building best practices

Tags: theming, 8

I'm looking for a group/community/post that can help guide me on the best practices for site building in Drupal 8.
I'm at a reasonable level for site building already but are seeking to share thoughts and ideas on best practices and the best way to build.
Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) This is a Q+A site for specific, narrowly scoped questions that can be answered objectively, I'm afraid sharing thoughts and ideas is beyond our scope. If you have a bunch of specific questions about the best practice way to achieve certain tasks, please ask each one separately, making sure to post what you've already tried, why/how they didn't work, or if they did work, what you think might not be optimal about the approach, etc. Many thanks

Comment: Also, _best way_ is always subjective: What is the best for you could not be the best for others. Instead of asking for tutorials/links, ask a question about a specific problem you have. If the question has a definitive, objective answer, then it can be acceptable for us.